# Showing that $f(x) \leq O(g(x))$.

Tags: asymptotics

I have two (strictly) positive functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$. I am required to show that $f(x) \leq O(g(x))$ for $x \to \pm \infty$.  I showed that $f(x) \leq kg(x)$ for $|x| \to \infty$. Is this enough ?

Comment: I've never seen $f(x) \leq O(g(x))$ before.

Comment: Perhaps $\le$ is due to the misconception that $O(g) = \Theta(g)$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what is meant by "for $x \rightarrow \dots", but this looks pretty close to the definition of $O(g(x))$, so OP likely has it mostly right but maybe an answerer will help explain the concepts.